# JUnit parameters methods of all tests running first in a suite, instead of before each test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, parameterized

The basic problem is, when I group JUnit tests into suites or suites of suites, the `@Parameters` method of all the tests runs first before the individual suites or tests execute. Our setup is as follows:

We have multiple test class files which each have static inner classes with the actual tests.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
   SubTestSuite01.TestSet01.class,
   SubTestSuite01.TestSet02.class})
public class SubTestSuite01 {
  public static class TestSet01{
    public TestSet01(){}
    @Parameters public static Collection<Object[]> data(){}
    @Test public void test01(){}
    @Test public void test02(){}
  }

  public static class TestSet02{
    public TestSet02(){}
    @Parameters public static Collection<Object[]> data(){}
    @Test public void test01(){}
    @Test public void test02(){}
  }
}
```

And so on for `SubTestSuite02`, `SubTestSuite03`, etc. Now to collect all these test suites into a larger collection, I've created a larger test suite as follows:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({SubTestSuite01.class, SubTestSuite02.class,SubTestSuite03.class})
public class AllTests{}
```

However, whether I'm running the `AllTests` master suite, or the `SubTestSuite`'s, the `@Parameters` method of all the inner classes are being called first across the entire suite / suites before any of the `@BeforeClass` methods or the actual test methods.

My questions are:

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. How can I have it run so that the `@Parameters` method of the individual inner classes runs just before it's own tests are executed and not together at the beginning of the suite?

With the current behavior, I run the risk of quickly overwhelming my system resources as various things are all loaded up together.

Comment: This setup is highly unusual. I would advise for a more normal setup and see how things behave there. As for the Parameters method running before the BeforeClass, in this case I think it would be the behavior I'd expect.

Comment: @baba Could you clarify what you mean by a more normal setup...? or why such a setup is out of the ordinary...?

Comment: Anyone....? any further clues...?

Answer (score 0):

*@Parameterized* will always run first, even before *@BeforeClass*

You don't have to use static classes and inner classes for your tests, I would have used classes to hold similar tests and [@Cetegories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) to select the groups

Comment: True, I don't need to use static inner classes. However, my problem is, however I organize the tests and suites, ALL the `@Parameterized` will run first across the entire suite/suites. I really need for a way to have it run for one test class at a time....